# Dynamically Forming a JSON object traversion without using eval

Tags: javascript, json, eval

Given I have the following: (which is dynamically generated and varies in length)

`associations = ["employer", "address"];`

Trying to traverse the JSON object, and wanting to form something like the following:

```
data.employer.address
```

or

`data[associations[0]][association[1]]`

Without doing this:

`eval("data."+associations.join('.'));`

Finally, I may be shunned for saying this, but is it okay to use eval in an instance like this? Just retrieving data.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just iterate over your associations?

```
function traverse(data, associations){
  for (var i=0; i<associations.length; i++){
      data = data[associations[i]];
  }
  return data;
}
```

Your eval method has to generate a new string and parse the code before it can even start traversing.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Anything hinting at recursion usually fries my brain.

Comment: In fact, simple iteration will be much faster (in Javascript) than recursion or functional reduce/fold.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s one way using Prototype.

```
$A(associations).inject(data, function (obj, method) {
  return obj[method];
});
```

Using `eval` is fine if you can guarantee the user won’t be able affect the string you’re passing to it. If your input is coming from the user or from a URL that could be changed by the user, you should probably avoid `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a dynamic script node.  For instance:

```
var yo = document.createElement("script");
yo.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
yo.innerHTML = "alert('yo!');";
document.body.appendChild(yo);
```

No eval required.